# Tableau Reports not showing in iPhone and iPad in asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iphone, ipad, tableau-api

I have an ASP.NET application in which I have embedded tableau reports with trusted authentication. These reports work just fine in all browsers, laptop and desktop. But on an iPhone or iPad whenever I am trying to open it, I get nothing.

I have searched a lot and tried all possibilities. I have `embed=yes` parameter but it's just not showing up. Here is my Javascript. In the label I am having a URL that looks like this (this is just an example):

```
https://online.tableau.com/t/Sales/views/test/test ?:embed=yes
```

I am use Javascript to find the `div` with `id=viz` and show report.
What can I do to make it work?

```
function call()
{
  var viz;
  var vizDivID = document.getElementById('viz');
  var lbl = document.getElementById('URLLabel');
  var URL = (lbl.innerHTML);

  viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(vizDivId, URL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this question for an answer

[X-Frame Option is set to allow but safari shows Refuse to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35349024/x-frame-option-is-set-to-allow-but-safari-shows-refuse-to-display)

If in case this will not work for you, you can refer to this post

https://community.tableau.com/thread/196157