# X-Frame Option is set to allow but safari shows Refuse to display

Tags: asp.net, iframe, safari, frames, x-frame-options

I am working on a application which embeds tableau report in iframe. It runs perfectly on all browsers other than safari. As shown in the 2nd image it shows that error "Refuse to display.." but I have changed all the setting and added X-Frame-Options in my header like this

```
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "ALLOWALL");
```

After adding this in response header it shows X-Frame-Options = AllowAll show in in image 2 but it gives same "Refuse to display error.."

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Please help me. For more info you can read

[link]  [Tableau Reports not showing in iPhone and iPad in asp.net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303859/tableau-reports-not-showing-in-iphone-and-ipad-in-asp-net-application)

[image: Header response shows X-Frame-Options Value]

[image: Safari shows error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that if you are accessing embedded tableau views in safari or any other browser. If they give the the same error as me shown above. Then You have to check your browser preferences. You need to allow third party cookies to view those embedded views in your application in any device. Here is the link where I found my answer.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm